# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onmouseover') error in javascript

Tags: javascript, events

I don't even know how or why this happens so I don't really know how to fix it.
I am on the newest version of Google Chrome. No JS frameworks.

I tried to make an interesting effect when I hover over this one piece of text using this code:

```js
const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrtuvwxyz01234567890"

let interval = null;
let ampm = 0;

document.getElementById("header").onmouseover = event => {  
    let iteration = 0;
    
    clearInterval(interval);
    
    interval = setInterval(() => {
        event.target.innerText = event.target.innerText
        .split("")
        .map((letter, index) => {
            if(index < iteration) {
                return event.target.dataset.value[index];
            }
            
            return letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 62)]
        })
        .join("");
            
        if(iteration >= event.target.dataset.value.length){ 
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        
        iteration += 1 / 5;
    }, 25);
}
```

The code that doesn't work here is

```js
document.getElementById("header").onmouseover = event => {  
}
```

My HTML is this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        
        <title>Kokice5</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script src="code.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body onload="startTime()">
        <p id="clock" style="text-align: center;" class="notranslate"></p>
        <h1 id="header" style="text-align: center; font-size: 15vw;" data-value="Kokice5">Kokice5</h1> <-- Header I would like to affect !-->
</body></html>
```

Error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onmouseover')`

What I expected to happen was [this](https://codepen.io/Hyperplexed/full/rNrJgrd).

Answer (score 0):

Move `<script src="code.js"></script>` right before the closing `</body>` tag so that the element it looks for exists at the time it is run.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your script tag as the last item in your body, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        
        <title>Kokice5</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    </head>
    <body onload="startTime()">
        <p id="clock" style="text-align: center;" class="notranslate"></p>
        <h1 id="header" style="text-align: center; font-size: 15vw;" data-value="Kokice5">Kokice5</h1> <-- Header I would like to affect !-->
        <script src="code.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

This is because your JavaScript file executes before the `<h1/>` element is created in the DOM. When it tries to find your element by id, it doesn't find anything and `getElementById` returns null.

`<script>` elements are often placed in the header, but to change when the JS executes, you can put certain boolean attributes into the element to such as `defer` or `async`. For example, you could keep your `<script>` where it is but change it to be

```
<script src="code.js" defer></script>
```

and your code would work how you want it to. For more on `defer`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer

See also: [Where should I put <script> tags in HTML markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup/24070373#24070373)